# Issue with nested generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have these definitions:

```
public interface IHasId
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}


public class Something : IHasId
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}


public class Queueable<T>
    where T : IHasId, new()
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public int QueueId { get; set; }
}


public class Queue<T>       
    where T : Queueable<T>, IHasId, new()
{
    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {

    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}


public class QueueService
{
    private Queue<Queueable<Something>> queue;
    //private Queue<Queueable<SomethingElse>> somethingElseQueue;
}
```

When I compile this I'm getting these errors:

```
**Error**: The type 'test.Queueable<test.Something>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'test.Queue<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'test.Queueable<test.Something>' to 'test.IHasId'.

**Error**: The type 'test.Queueable<test.Something>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'test.Queue<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'test.Queueable<test.Something>' to 'test.Queueable<test.Queueable<test.Something>>'.
```

Is this a problem of constraints?
I'm thinking on using 2 types for the Queue class, one for the one implementing the IHasId and the other for the Queueable but I'm hoping this is actually simpler to resolve.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!
R.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the `Queue<T>` class?

Comment: Yes, sorry, added now.

Comment: `Queueable<T>` is not `IHasId` just because  its `T` is, but your `Queue` class expects it to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I interpret your intention correctly, you want this:

```
public class Queue<T>       
    where T : IHasId, new()
{
    public void Enqueue(Queueable<T> item)
    {
    }

    public Queueable<T> Dequeue()
    {
        return default(Queueable<T>);
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public class Queue<TItem, TQueueable>   
    where TItem : IHasId, new()
    where TQueueable: Queueable<TItem>
{
    public void Enqueue(TQueueable<TItem> item)
    {
    }

    public TQueueable<TItem> Dequeue()
    {
        return default(TQueueable<TItem>);
    }
}
```

The last one is the post flexible form possible.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Duh! Thanks! Will try this

Comment: I came up with something similar to the second alternative you are suggesting (hence my comment about accepting 2 types in the question) but the 1st suggestion actually makes way more sense as the solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Queue<T>       
    where T : Queueable<T>, IHasId, new()
{ ... }
```

As you can see, the `T` inside `Queue<T>` needs to be both of `IHasId` and `Queueable<T>` but the type you put in, `Queueable<Something>`, isn’t.

You will need to implement both `IHasId` and `Queueable<>` on the `Queueable<T>` type as well. Note that you will probably introduce some more names for the generic type other than `T` to prevent some recursive requirements or something.

Comment: I'm not following. Something implements IHasId, and Queueable<Something> is in compliance with both requirements. What am I missing?

Comment: "Something" does, but not the thing that needs too according to your constraint.

Comment: In `Queue<Queueable<Something>>` the `T` of `Queue<T>` is `Queueable<Something>` with the constraints `T : Queueable<T>, IHasId`. If you would expand this, it would be something like `Queueable<Something> : Queueable<Queueable<Something>>, IHasId`. I’m not even sure if that would actually make any sense. You should check your constraints.

Comment: Yes, you guys are right. The other answer actually is suggesting a better approach to my initial idea; but you made a valid point here too. Thanks!